# Why are the two rectifiers in an AC Power adapter?

Tags: power, ac, rectifier, adapter

I am currently learning how an AC Power adapter works, and I learned that the incoming voltage is first filtered, then rectified, then converted back to AC using a transient switch, transformed, then rectified again and output. Why is the first rectification needed?

German drawing:

[image]

Comment: Do you have a reference for that.. Seems like a very specific application.

Comment: @Trevor, unless the "converted back to AC ... transformed, then rectified again" part is meant to be a description of a switching converter.

Comment: This is probably a duplicate. However, this is most often done to invert the electricity at a higher frequency before passing it to some sort of inductor design to make more efficient use of the inductor.

Comment: @ThePhoton true... I guess I read "converted back to AC" too literally :)

Comment: @matsbauer, It would be interesting to see the whole context (link) where this comes from (even if it's *auf Deutsch*).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Brief answer:
This is called a Switched Mode Power Supply. Mains frequency is at around 50Hz-60Hz. If you used a transformer designed for this frequency to convert your 230V to 5V, it would have to be very big and heavy.

We deal with this by increasing the frequency to several KHz, which allows us to decrease the size of the transformer for various reasons. To change the frequency like this, we first need to get rough DC, and then connect it to the input of our transformer through a switch. We then turn this switch on and off very fast (several KHz) to get the high frequency transformer input that we want. This input is then transformed to 5V, and rectified to provide a 5VDC output.

Comment: The associated question should be, why do we need the DC to convert into high-kHz switching signal? I think the answer is: slow changing 50/60Hz AC signal will have instant amplitudes from zero to ~300V and back. It will be much more difficult to design electronics that accommodates this huge voltage swing, and equally work with alternating polarity. So rectification to DC (even with substantial ripples) is the solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is a symbolic block diagram and not a detailed design.  So the diode  indicates rectification from AC to DC even if done using an IC with 4 synchronous transistor switches for active PFC.

There is also not shown a complementary side for differential full wave rectification and a Common Mode CM choke on the primary side.

The power goes from AC to high V DC then switched complementary  AC then rectifed DC fed back to regulate the AC duty cycle using the PWM full bridge before the ferrite transformer at some high f.